# Who should be the Moderator for Geographic Information Systems?

Tags: discussion, top-7

About 7 days into our public beta, the Stack Exchange team is going to select a few provisional moderators for this community until we can hold our own elections.

See: [**Moderator Pro Tempore**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/)

Some guidelines:

- Each nomination should be a separate answer. Link the name to the user's profile so we can see their activity.
- The nominee should indicate their acceptance by commenting on (or indeed editing) the answer.
- The top voted nominations can go forward to the vote.
- The voting will be done on a separate question.

The candidate:

- Must be a currently registered user in good standing
- Must have a reasonably high reputation score to indicate active, consistent participation.
- Should exhibit patience and fairness at all times in their questions, answers, and comments.
- Should lead by example, showing respect for their fellow community members in everything they write.
- They should want the responsibility. Nominating users isn’t the same as an obligation. It’s purely voluntary!

(With thanks to [ChrisF](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/271/revisions) for the guidelines and candidate qualifications.)

Comment: This is a good question to ask, but it feels to me too early in the community to have a good sense of candidates participation, which seems important to me as a filter.

Comment: I agree - we've only been running one week

Comment: I also agree.  I'm mod-ing on Pro Webmasters and it's freaking scary; worried about messing up the fledgling community by being over-enthusiastic, etc. :)  Give us some time to set norms and establish a community first.

Comment: If you don't lend a hand at selecting some outstanding community members, I am going to be selecting them arbitrarily: [**Moderator Pro Tempore**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/)

Comment: @JasonBirch: This process typically starts during the private beta. At the end of the first week of the *public* beta, the names are already being selected.

Answer (score 10):

### Kirk Kuykendall

Kirk is a very active member of the GIS community with contributions to many ESRI forums. He is truly a GIS expert.

I'm not sure if the has the time or the will, but he would be a nice moderator, mainly for his experience and patience.

[GIS profile](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/users/59/kirk-kuykendall)

Comment: +1 finally, one that I can vote for (couldn't vote for ones I created) :) Here's hoping Kirk accepts the nom!  Hmm shouldn't have shortened that, now feeling hungry...

Answer (score 6):

### SCW

I nominate Shaun Walbridge.

[@scw](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/143/scw) has been active on both the main site and in meta, and consistently gives well thought out and considerate answers and comments.

GIS profile: https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/143/scw

Meta GIS profile: https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/users/143/scw

Comment: +1 scw would be a good moderator!

Comment: I'd be happy to moderate as needed, thanks for the nomination.

Comment: I agree, scw's answers are consistently well researched and often have a significant amount of effort put in (see for example http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/618/how-to-represent-bimodal-attribute-value-distributions-on-a-map/647#647 ).

Answer (score 6):

### JasonBirch

I ([@JasonBirch](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/64/jasonbirch)) am willing to act as temporary moderator if nobody else steps forward between now and when the SE folks select moderators.

I do think there are likely folks better suited to do so ([@fmark](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/145/fmark), [@Kirk Kuykendall](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/59/kirk-kuykendall), [@matt wilkie](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/108/matt-wilkie), probably more) based on some of the answers I've come across on the main site and involvement in meta.

There also may be some SO heavyweights in this project based on the initial commitments, though I don't know if any actually followed through; it would be useful to have at least one of our community mods be a high-level SO user with some experience with the mod tools.

Comment: +1. Jason is following the project since it started and helped spreading the word.

Answer (score 5):

### George

I nominate George Silva for the position of a Moderator Pro Tem.

[@George](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/5/george) is the initial proposer for the GIS site, has actively promoted it in various different venues, and has taken an active role in both the main site and meta since its launch.  George is also active in other Area51 sites.

area51 profile: http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/154/george
gis.stackexchange profile: https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/5/george
meta.gis.stackexchange profile: https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/users/5/george

Comment: +1 Ahh, I didn't realize this George is George Silva.  He's also been active on the ESRI forums.
http://forums.arcgis.com/search.php?searchid=64735

Comment: Thanks for the confidence. If it's the case, after the voting wins, I'll help moderate gis.stackexchange :D
Thanks guys.

Comment: with respect george is obviously very enthusiastic but his points seem to have been mostly earnt through quantity rather than quality of posting.